# How to remove delay when reading file and issuing command

Tags: python

I am reading log file from LINUX server using python. I would like to send a command when specific text appears in the log file.

**Question** - there is a delay, by the time I read the file and issue the command hence I am unable to send command when that specific text appears

Note: logincommand is a function that I've created that issues command on Linux server

```
value = logincommand("cat /logs/test.log")
if "text1" in value:
    logincommand("reboot")
    return True
    break
else:
    print "text1 has to appear yet"
    return False
```

Comment: it's unclear to me what you are being prevented from doing by a delay in reading the file...

Comment: What causes the delay?  Is it comms to the server, or buffering?  Would you be better using something like `tail -f`?

Comment: Can't you run the whole "if 'text1' in file, reboot" logic on the server? Sending commands back and forth is always going to cause some delay.

Comment: @cdarke - tried tail -f and I see same thing (i.e. same delay)

Comment: @Rawing - would you please elaborate? How can I achieve the same?

Comment: @beginner_user For example, execute something like `logincommand('''python -c "import os; if 'text1' in open('/logs/test.log').read(): os.system('reboot')"''')`. That would eliminate some of the communication between the server and your PC.